# How to use a template view in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to use an existing template in prestashop (product-list.tpl), i use this code in my module controller (method: initContent() ):

```
$this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_ . 'templates/catalog/listing/product-list.tpl');
```

But prestashop return me that error :

```
[PrestaShopException]
No template found for C:\wamp64\www\prestashop/themes/classic/templates/catalog/listing/product-list.tpl
at line 68 in file classes/Smarty/TemplateFinder.php
```

Thank's you very much for you'r help !

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the method setTemplate(), which is calling getTemplatePath(), a method that check if the desired template is located either in the module directory or in the module directory inside the current theme.

To make it work i would simply copy the `product-list.tpl` inside the directory :
`"YourTheme"/modules/"Your module"/views/templates/front/`

Comment: Hi, thank's for you'r answer, i try your code but i get same issue :
`No template found for C:\wamp64\www\prestashop/themes/classic/product-list.tpl
at line 68 in file classes/Smarty/TemplateFinder.php`

Thank's you

Comment: Edited my answer, can you try it ?

Comment: Look at my new answer